# Greeting program raises NameError

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
varname = input("what is your name?: ")
print ("Hello", varname)
```

Does anybody know why this wont work? Just prints

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sfawcett/Desktop/python.py", line 1, in <module>
    varname = input("what is your name?: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Lewis' is not defined
```

Comment: I've added the python 2 tag. Please correct me if I'm wrong @user3801278

Comment: what version of python u using???

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between raw\_input() and input() in python3.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input()` evaluates string. To get raw value you should use `raw_input()`

Answer (score 0):

In python3:-

```
In [4]: varname = input("what is your name?: ")
what is your name?: lewis

In [5]: print ("Hello", varname)
Hello lewis
```

in python2:-

read [here about input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input)

```
In [185]: varname = raw_input("what is your name?: ") #don't use `input()`
what is your name?: lewis

In [186]: print ("Hello", varname)
('Hello', 'lewis')
```